# Transpose row to columns in SQL/PHP

Tags: mysql, sql

I fetched the following data:

```html
MONTH      |      TOTAL
-------------------------
Jan        |      100
Feb        |      200
Mar        |      300
```

Using this query:

```
$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%b') AS MONTH, SUM(col1+col2) AS TOTAL FROM myTable GROUP BY YEAR(date),MONTH(date)";
```

How can I edit the above query or re-write to get the following result:

```html
JAN | FEB | MAR
-------------------------
100 | 200 | 300
```

I have gone through almost all the the other similar posts. However, sql transposing, to me, is very confusing. Any input is much appreciated!

Comment: Your question is tagged SQL Server, but your code is not SQL Server code.  Please fix the tag.

Comment: why your question tag is php?

Comment: You have 2 `Feb` and no `MAR` in the first example of the data, not to mention the casing is different.  I would think you would need the Year as well as The month in the output,  `Feb` what 2019 or 2018 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  The following will work in either SQL Server or MySQL:

```
select year(date),
       sum(case when month(date) = 1 then col1 + col2 else 0 end) as jan,
       sum(case when month(date) = 2 then col1 + col2 else 0 end) as feb,
       sum(case when month(date) = 3 then col1 + col2 else 0 end) as mar
from mytable
group by year(date)
order by year(date);
```

EDIT (regarding the comment):

```
select year(date),
       sum(case when month(date) = 1 then val else 0 end) as jan,
       sum(case when month(date) = 2 then val else 0 end) as feb,
       sum(case when month(date) = 3 then val else 0 end) as mar
from (select t.*, (col1 + col2) as val
      from mytable
     ) t
group by year(date)
order by year(date);
```

Comment: Is there any way to use some variable like "total=col+col2 so that I can use it repeatedly? My actual table has about 20 columns.   Please forgive my ignorance, I'm working on a personal project to learn coding myself. Your answers help me to learn faster. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @alien250 . . . In MySQL, you would use a subquery to do the calculation.